# Parsing XML Data, issue with my loops

Tags: python, xml, for-loop, xml-parsing

I am learning python as my first programming language and I am currently working on parsing an xml file as an exercise.  I am having an issue when I go to print.

Within the AWARD_CONTRACT tag, there are multiple contractors, have been awarded the contract.  When I go to print the AWARD_CONTRACT, only the last contractor is printed.  Please see the code below.  Also any tips on how to clean up the code or make this more efficient would be appreciated!

```
<AWARD_CONTRACT ITEM="1"> 
  <CONTRACT_NO>1</CONTRACT_NO>  
  <LOT_NO>1</LOT_NO>  
  <TITLE> 
    <P>Vállalkozási szerződés</P> 
  </TITLE>  
  <AWARDED_CONTRACT> 
    <DATE_CONCLUSION_CONTRACT>2016-12-28</DATE_CONCLUSION_CONTRACT>  
    <NB_TENDERS_RECEIVED>5</NB_TENDERS_RECEIVED>  
    <NB_TENDERS_RECEIVED_SME>0</NB_TENDERS_RECEIVED_SME>  
    <NB_TENDERS_RECEIVED_OTHER_EU>0</NB_TENDERS_RECEIVED_OTHER_EU>  
    <NB_TENDERS_RECEIVED_NON_EU>0</NB_TENDERS_RECEIVED_NON_EU>  
    <NB_TENDERS_RECEIVED_EMEANS>0</NB_TENDERS_RECEIVED_EMEANS>  
    <AWARDED_TO_GROUP/>  
    <CONTRACTOR> 
      <ADDRESS_CONTRACTOR> 
        <OFFICIALNAME>SWIETELSKY Magyarország Kft.</OFFICIALNAME>  
        <ADDRESS>Irinyi J. u. 4-20. B. épület V. emelet</ADDRESS>  
        <TOWN>Budapest</TOWN>  
        <POSTAL_CODE>1117</POSTAL_CODE>  
        <COUNTRY VALUE="HU"/>  
        <NUTS CODE="HU101"/> 
      </ADDRESS_CONTRACTOR>  
      <NO_SME/> 
    </CONTRACTOR>  
    <CONTRACTOR> 
      <ADDRESS_CONTRACTOR> 
        <OFFICIALNAME>HE-DO Kft.</OFFICIALNAME>  
        <ADDRESS>Váci út 76.</ADDRESS>  
        <TOWN>Budapest</TOWN>  
        <POSTAL_CODE>1133</POSTAL_CODE>  
        <COUNTRY VALUE="HU"/>  
        <NUTS CODE="HU101"/> 
      </ADDRESS_CONTRACTOR>  
      <NO_SME/> 
    </CONTRACTOR>  
    <CONTRACTOR> 
      <ADDRESS_CONTRACTOR> 
        <OFFICIALNAME>KM Építő Kft.</OFFICIALNAME>  
        <ADDRESS>Bánki Donát u. 5.</ADDRESS>  
        <TOWN>Szigetszentmiklós</TOWN>  
        <POSTAL_CODE>2310</POSTAL_CODE>  
        <COUNTRY VALUE="HU"/>  
        <NUTS CODE="HU102"/> 
      </ADDRESS_CONTRACTOR>  
      <NO_SME/> 
    </CONTRACTOR>  
    <VAL_ESTIMATED_TOTAL CURRENCY="HUF">9000000000</VAL_ESTIMATED_TOTAL>  
    <VAL_TOTAL CURRENCY="HUF">9270494617</VAL_TOTAL> 
  </AWARDED_CONTRACT> 
</AWARD_CONTRACT>
```

MY CODE IS AS FOLLOWS:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse('91414-2017.xml')

award_contract = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('AWARD_CONTRACT')
for award in award_contract:
    item_no = award.getAttribute("ITEM")
    contract_no = award.getElementsByTagName('CONTRACT_NO')[0]
    lot = award.getElementsByTagName('LOT_NO')[0]
    title = award.getElementsByTagName('TITLE')[0]
    date = award.getElementsByTagName('DATE_CONCLUSION_CONTRACT')[0]

    contractors = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('CONTRACTOR')
    for contractor in contractors:
        name = contractor.getElementsByTagName('OFFICIALNAME')[0]
        address = contractor.getElementsByTagName('ADDRESS')[0]
        town = contractor.getElementsByTagName('TOWN')[0]
        zip_code = contractor.getElementsByTagName('POSTAL_CODE')[0]
        c = contractor.getElementsByTagName('COUNTRY')[0]
        country = c.getAttribute("VALUE")

    value = award.getElementsByTagName('VAL_TOTAL')[0]
    currency = value.getAttribute("CURRENCY")

    print(item_no, ',', contract_no.firstChild.data,',', lot.firstChild.data,
      ',', title.firstChild.data,',', date.firstChild.data,',',
      name.firstChild.data,',', address.firstChild.data,',', town.firstChild.data,',',
      zip_code.firstChild.data,',', country, ',', value.firstChild.data,',', currency)
```

Comment: Use LibXML2, xpathNewContext() and xpathEval() to do the job properly with xpath.

Comment: Even when OP need XPath, Python has specific set of libraries that supports XPath with simpler API..

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're replacing value of variables `name`, `address`, `town`, etc. in every iteration of the inner `for` loop, so only the values from the last iteration remained. Since you only need those values for printing in this case, you can just move the code for printing, and all variables to be printed that currently still outside of the inner loop, inside the inner loop. This way it will print the variable values just before it get replaced with the new values in the next iteration :

```
for contractor in contractors:
    ......
    country = c.getAttribute("VALUE")

    value = award.getElementsByTagName('VAL_TOTAL')[0]
    currency = value.getAttribute("CURRENCY")

    print(item_no, ',', contract_no.firstChild.data,',', ...... )
```

When your parsing task get more complex, for example, you need to find elements with speicifc criteria instead of just reading every elements, using `minidom` can be painful, I'd suggest [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/), or, at the very least, [`xml.etree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: @joe You're welcome. Btw, since you haven't done it so far, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer that solved the problem being asked..